# Bluetooth BTstack HID keypad dissconects after ~30 seconds

Tags: c, bluetooth, keyboard, raspberry-pi-pico

Everything works except my BTstack HID keypad will disconnect after about thirty seconds. I can reconnect but it will disconnect again. I am using [this tutorial](https://rfwumcu.blogspot.com/2023/06/raspberry-pi-pico-w-btstack-ep-4-hid.html) to create a Bluetooth keyboard with the Raspberry Pi Pico W.

BT_custom_keypad.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"
#include "hid_keyboard_demo.c" //line 363 commented

void send_hid_text(uint8_t* text) {
    btstack_ring_buffer_write(&send_buffer, text, strlen(text));
    send_next(NULL);
    busy_wait_ms(100);
}

void send_hid_char(uint8_t c) {
    btstack_ring_buffer_write(&send_buffer, (uint8_t*)&c, 1);
    send_next(NULL);
    busy_wait_ms(100);
}

void send_hid_spec_code(uint8_t m, uint8_t c) {
    send_modifier = m;
    send_keycode = c;
    hid_device_request_can_send_now_event(hid_cid);
}


int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    if (cyw43_arch_init()) {
        printf("cyw43 arch init error\n");
        return 0;
    }


    btstack_main(0, NULL);
    gap_set_local_name("PicoW Keypad");


    while(1) {

        busy_wait_ms(2000);
        send_hid_text("messages...\n");

        tight_loop_contents();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

btStack_config.h

```
#ifndef _PICO_BTSTACK_BTSTACK_CONFIG_H
#define _PICO_BTSTACK_BTSTACK_CONFIG_H

// BTstack features that can be enabled
#ifdef ENABLE_BLE
#define ENABLE_LE_PERIPHERAL
#define ENABLE_LE_CENTRAL
#define ENABLE_L2CAP_LE_CREDIT_BASED_FLOW_CONTROL_MODE
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_MESH
// Mesh Config
#define ENABLE_MESH_ADV_BEARER
#define ENABLE_MESH_GATT_BEARER
#define ENABLE_MESH_PB_ADV
#define ENABLE_MESH_PB_GATT
#define ENABLE_MESH_PROXY_SERVER
#define ENABLE_MESH_RELAY

#define ENABLE_MESH_PROVISIONER

#define MAX_NR_MESH_SUBNETS            2
#define MAX_NR_MESH_TRANSPORT_KEYS    16
#define MAX_NR_MESH_VIRTUAL_ADDRESSES 16
// allow for one NetKey update
#define MAX_NR_MESH_NETWORK_KEYS      (MAX_NR_MESH_SUBNETS+1)
#endif


#define ENABLE_LOG_INFO
#define ENABLE_LOG_ERROR
#define ENABLE_PRINTF_HEXDUMP
#define ENABLE_SCO_OVER_HCI

// BTstack configuration. buffers, sizes, ...
#define HCI_OUTGOING_PRE_BUFFER_SIZE 4
#define HCI_ACL_PAYLOAD_SIZE (1691 + 4)
#define HCI_ACL_CHUNK_SIZE_ALIGNMENT 4
#define MAX_NR_AVDTP_CONNECTIONS 1
#define MAX_NR_AVDTP_STREAM_ENDPOINTS 1
#define MAX_NR_AVRCP_CONNECTIONS 2
#define MAX_NR_BNEP_CHANNELS 1
#define MAX_NR_BNEP_SERVICES 1
#define MAX_NR_BTSTACK_LINK_KEY_DB_MEMORY_ENTRIES  2
#define MAX_NR_GATT_CLIENTS 1
#define MAX_NR_HCI_CONNECTIONS 2
#define MAX_NR_HID_HOST_CONNECTIONS 1
#define MAX_NR_HIDS_CLIENTS 1
#define MAX_NR_HFP_CONNECTIONS 1
#define MAX_NR_L2CAP_CHANNELS  4
#define MAX_NR_L2CAP_SERVICES  3
#define MAX_NR_RFCOMM_CHANNELS 1
#define MAX_NR_RFCOMM_MULTIPLEXERS 1
#define MAX_NR_RFCOMM_SERVICES 1
#define MAX_NR_SERVICE_RECORD_ITEMS 4
#define MAX_NR_SM_LOOKUP_ENTRIES 3
#define MAX_NR_WHITELIST_ENTRIES 16
#define MAX_NR_LE_DEVICE_DB_ENTRIES 16

// Limit number of ACL/SCO Buffer to use by stack to avoid cyw43 shared bus overrun
#define MAX_NR_CONTROLLER_ACL_BUFFERS 3
#define MAX_NR_CONTROLLER_SCO_PACKETS 3

// Enable and configure HCI Controller to Host Flow Control to avoid cyw43 shared bus overrun
#define ENABLE_HCI_CONTROLLER_TO_HOST_FLOW_CONTROL
#define HCI_HOST_ACL_PACKET_LEN 1024
#define HCI_HOST_ACL_PACKET_NUM 3
#define HCI_HOST_SCO_PACKET_LEN 120
#define HCI_HOST_SCO_PACKET_NUM 3

// Link Key DB and LE Device DB using TLV on top of Flash Sector interface
#define NVM_NUM_DEVICE_DB_ENTRIES 16
#define NVM_NUM_LINK_KEYS 16

// We don't give btstack a malloc, so use a fixed-size ATT DB.
#define MAX_ATT_DB_SIZE 512

// BTstack HAL configuration
#define HAVE_EMBEDDED_TIME_MS

// map btstack_assert onto Pico SDK assert()
#define HAVE_ASSERT

// Some USB dongles take longer to respond to HCI reset (e.g. BCM20702A).
#define HCI_RESET_RESEND_TIMEOUT_MS 1000

#define ENABLE_SOFTWARE_AES128
#define ENABLE_MICRO_ECC_FOR_LE_SECURE_CONNECTIONS

//#define HAVE_BTSTACK_STDIN

// To get the audio demos working even with HCI dump at 115200, this truncates long ACL packets
//#define HCI_DUMP_STDOUT_MAX_SIZE_ACL 100

#ifdef ENABLE_CLASSIC
#define ENABLE_L2CAP_ENHANCED_RETRANSMISSION_MODE
#endif

#define HAVE_MALLOC

#endif // _PICO_BTSTACK_BTSTACK_CONFIG_H
```

Comment: What does you log from the pico and the connected device say?

Comment: I believe starting [btmon](https://manpages.org/btmon) in another terminal on your pico would be a great start